# Can a lawyer compel a witness to read something aloud in court?

Tags: court, trial, rules-of-evidence

Often on shows like Law and Order, a lawyer might ask someone on the stand to read something aloud. An example might be an academic putting forward one opinion, being asked to read an excerpt from a journal article they authored 20 years prior that contradicts what they are currently saying (this happened in one episode).

Could the person on the stand refuse? Surely the lawyer can read it themselves or show the text on a projector to the court, and having the person read the text out loud might influence the jury and affect the outcome in a negative way for the person on trial.

Is this just TV drama, or is there a legal basis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you used the Law & Order example, I'll assume you're talking about a criminal case in the United States.

No, the witness may not refuse to answer, because yes, there is a legal basis for requiring a person to read something out loud. The point of a subpoena is that it legally compels you to appear and testify, and to testify fully and truthfully about whatever you are asked. More specifically, a criminal defendant has a Sixth Amendment right to force witnesses to appear and testify.

On a more practical note, it is not really the case that a lawyer could simply read the article into evidence. If he has the witness on direct examination, asking the question as "Doesn't your article say that *x*?" would be a leading question, in violation of [Rule 611](https://www.law.cornell.edu/rules/fre/rule_611), and even on a cross-examination, when leading is allowed, an attorney's question about what the article says is still just a question, not evidence. The jury should not, from his question, draw a conclusion that he is correct about the contents of the article.

Moreover, there are certain instances where statements may be read to the jury but are explicitly prohibited from being submitted to the jury as an exhibit ([Rule 803(18)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/rules/fre/rule_803)), which really requires you to ask the witness to read it out loud.

An image projected on a wall isn't in the record. You need someone to read the words out loud so the stenographer can take them down. The person reading can't be the attorney or bailiff because they aren't under oath, meaning what they say isn't evidence, and the jury can't treat it as evidence. If you want the jury to consider it, you need the witness's testimony.

Comment: Rule 611(a)(2) ("*presenting evidence as to [...] avoid wasting time*") contradicts your answer. Most likely it will take longer for a witness to read his document aloud than to concretely confirm or deny his authorship of that document or of relevant statements therein. Also 611(c) permits leading questions on direct examination"*as necessary to develop the witness's testimony*".And the issue (per context given by the OP) is not "*[who] is correct about the contents of the article*", but the inconsistency of the witness's statements (given the impact this could have on witness's credibility).

Comment: An interesting reading of the rule! I don't know many courts that would find it persuasive.

Comment: What about the issue of it being prejudicial (brought up by Iñaki Viggers)? If the paper (mentioned by OP) was from 20 years ago, having an expert witness read it may create the impression that the witness espouses both opinions *today*.  While, in fact, an expert's opinions can evolve over time based on new information.

Comment: Inaki's answer is incorrect in its suggestion that prejudice is a valid basis for an objection. The entire point of the adversarial system is to present evidence prejudicial to the other side. The real issue implicated by this hypothetical is whether the risk of misleading the jury substantially outweighs the probative value of the evidence. This is a valid basis for an objection. but a weak one. I'd expect most judges to require the witness to answer and allow the other side to rehabilitate the witness on redirect.

Comment: Either way, that objection belongs to the parties, not the witness. Outside of questions about privileged information, the witness herself has essentially no right to refuse to answer questions, and certainly not to avoid seeming inconsistent. If there's a problem with the question, one of the parties can object. If no one objects, or if the objection is overruled, the witness must answer, even if the answer makes her look stupid.

Comment: I understand your point that the objection belongs to the parties and not the witness.  Another point which seems to be sidestepped by everyone claiming to be a lawyer here is OP's confusion (which to some extent I share) as to why this is called a "question."  While a witness can be compelled to answer a question, this is essentially asking for a public performance.  There is no interrogatory here.  The information is already available to the court in the written format.  The only interrogatory purpose this can serve is to voir dire a witness' ability to read.

Comment: That distinction is overly formalistic, I think. It's pretty uncontroversial to treat lots of sentences as questions, even if they aren't grammatically structured as them. For instance, leading questions are very frequently phrased simply as short, declarative sentences, but with a rising inflection: "And then you heard a bang?" Everyone accepts that this amounts to the question: "Did you then hear a bang?" Likewise, requesting that a witness read a document into the record is the functional equivalent of asking, "What does this document say?"

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am still absorbing it! Could you clarify what the legal basis is that would compel a witness to read something aloud, instead of having the attorney read it aloud, or have the bailiff read it aloud while it is showed on a projector?

Comment: You're welcome! I've updated the answer to address this issue; check out the last paragraph. And just as a practical matter, courts generally give lawyers a lot of room to present their case in whatever manner they think is most persuasive. When it comes to any given trial strategy, the question is usually whether there's a rule against it, rather than a rule that allows it.

Comment: Ah thank you! That last paragraph really explaining the logic behind it. Just another question, but do you know if other countries and legal systems have similar reasoning and requirements that would require a witness to read something out loud?

Comment: My answer would be at least roughly correct anywhere that used to be part of the British Empire. As for other countries, I don't really know what the rules would be.

Comment: @bdb484 "*The entire point of the adversarial system is to present evidence prejudicial to the other side*". This makes no sense. Coming up with such inaccuracies in your criticism of other's answer (whether or not you tag its author) will mislead the audience which might not be acquainted with law concepts. Black's Law Dictionary defines *prejudice* as "*bias; preconceived opinion. A leaning towards one side of a cause for some reason other than a conviction of its justice*". Contrary to your assertion, the adversarial system is precisely to prevent conclusions from being *prejudicial*.

Comment: That definition is from the 1891 edition of Black's, which I think we can agree is comically outdated. The current version reflects current usage, defining prejudice as "[d]amage or detriment to one's legal rights or claims."

Comment: @bdb484 Feel free to share a link to the current version. I took this definition from the [4th edition](http://heimatundrecht.de/sites/default/files/dokumente/Black%27sLaw4th.pdf), which you can see is from 1968, not 1891. More important, the contemporary usage of this excerpt among US courts is palpable in decisions such as [*State v. Garoutte*, (Court of Appeals of WA, 2013)](https://www.leagle.com/decision/inwaco20130524e45). Let's see whether or not you have the courage to tell those judges that they are comically outdated.

Comment: The current is available through Westlaw: https://1.next.westlaw.com/Document/I02d69363808511e4b391a0bc737b01f9/View/FullText.html I'll see if I can muster the courage next time I run into Judge Siddoway.

Comment: Very "useful". Like every reader on SE has a Westlaw account and can verify that the latest edition defines *prejudice* only as you quoted it.

Comment: I doubt any reader on SE cares that you were wrong. But you could also visit a library if you're having trouble letting go of this one.

Answer (score 4):

> Could the person on the stand refuse?

Yes. The witness may refuse to read it aloud, which does not mean he cannot be compelled to do so. The witness may object on grounds you mention (prejudice) only if he is the defendant. Either way, the judge will make a decision on how that evidence is to be presented to the jury.

Regardless of who reads the evidence, the witness may be ordered to answer the question of whether or not he authored that document. Defying that order could result in *contempt of court* or, depending on the context, the entry of an [adverse inference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverse_inference).

Comment: Indeed, having a witness read something on the stand is routinely done. I do so in the majority of trials and evidentiary hearings in which I am an attorney and there is rarely a rule of evidence that prohibits the question (unless the document read would otherwise have been inadmissible as evidence, or is irrelevant completely to the case). Once a defendant chose to testify, the defendant could not object to the question based on prejudice even in a criminal trial, and could not object in a civil trial either base on mere prejudice.

Comment: When you say "the witness may refuse to read it aloud," what would be the legal basis for that?

Comment: @bdb484 "*what would be the legal basis for that?*" The issue of *who* reads the evidence aloud does not change its relevance or admissibility, nor does it narrow the issues for trial. Thus, the witness may object on grounds of *wasting time* and/or *unfair prejudice*, which would not affect whatsoever the probative value of the document itself. See [Rule 403](https://www.rulesofevidence.org/article-iv/rule-403/). A court might also preclude it as *repetitious evidence*, as it did in [*Witt Properties v. Schaeffer* (Apr.23, 2020)](https://www.leagle.com/decision/inwico20200423n42) at ¶12.

Comment: All of this sort of seems to rely on the judge intervening. I read the OP's question to ask whether the witness could make that decision himself, but I could be reading it wrong.

Comment: @bdb484 Indeed, the judge intervenes and has the last word, but his intervention could be prompted by the witness's decision to refuse/object to read aloud. Hence the 2nd statement in this answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! @ohwilleke you say it is routinely done, but what is the legal basis to enforce it? If a witness did not cooperate, what law are they breaking, and why could you not read it aloud yourself?

Comment: @bdb484 Indeed I was asking about if the witness was free to make a choice in this matter.

Comment: @JakeRankin A witness may be compelled to answer under threat of being held in direct contempt of court. The judge may throw the witness in jail or fine the witness on the spot, without a trial, for conduct contrary to correct courtroom behavior that takes place in a courtroom, and refusing to answer a question from a lawyer would count as such conduct.

Comment: @ohwilleke I understand all of that as to why a witness can be compelled to answer, but that isn't an answer to my question. A witness refusing to read a statement is not the same thing as a witness refusing to answer a question, surely.

Comment: @JakeRankin The point is that the witness's refusal to read aloud could be approved by the judge. But if the judge rejects witness's petition and the witness persists on his refusal, that is where the witness would be held in contempt of court. The fact that refusal was about reading aloud rather than about answering a question makes no difference on the legal outcome: contempt of court. Hence the importance for the witness to persuade the judge on why he should be excused from reading the document aloud. But all this stems from the witness's *decision* to object to (or deny) lawyer's request.

Comment: Doesn't framing an answer that way undermine its potential usefulness? If the law is generally straightforward on the idea of not killing people, for instance, it seems unhelpful to say, "Yes, you are allowed to kill people, because you may be able to persuade a judge that the killing was justified (although you'll be sentenced to death if that doesn't work out)."

Comment: @bdb484 "*Doesn't framing an answer that way undermine its potential usefulness?*" It is more useful than answering that "*'Doesn't your article say that x?' would be a leading question, in violation of Rule 611*" without noticing that Rule 611(a)(2) seeks to *avoid waste of time* (including witness's time). It is pointless to call a witness (even with a subpoena) to the stand for something that pretty much any literate person can do: reading a document aloud. It is also more useful than premising the answer on the bare purpose of a subpoena, since oftentimes subpoenas are used vexatiously.

Comment: @bdb484 Also the "analogy" of "*[being] allowed to kill people*" is too much of a stretch. The act of killing is irreversible, whereas the hindrance and effects of a witness's reluctance to read aloud are easy to overcome. The OP's question clearly pertains to the latter context.

Comment: Of course it does. Good work.

Comment: "Hence the importance for the witness to persuade the judge on why he should be excused from reading the document aloud." - Would most judges agree with you on principle if it was a bunch of hate speech? Not 'prejudice', not 'wasting time'. On principle.

Comment: @Mazura "*Would most judges agree with you on principle if it was a bunch of hate speech?*" That is hard to tell, in part because subjectivity, [un-]predictability, and idiosyncrasy vary among judges. Also because notions such as *prejudice* are inextricable from one tenet (or principle) of the administration of justice: to make jurors focus on the substance of the case.